# I can't set front page properly in drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I use theme "ePro" from theme forest and facing with a problem. When I try to change front page from Configuration -> System -> Basic site settings it mixing with default theme front page. How fix it and set node I want to set

Comment: What do you mean by "mixing"?